# Javafx TreeTableView with HashMap values

Tags: java, javafx, hashmap, javafx-8, treetableview

It is relatively easy to populate a javafx treetableview column this kind of code: `nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new TreeItemPropertyValueFactory<>("name"));`
This way, the column `nameColumn` can be linked to the underlying datatype with the field "name". This is of cource good if there can only be a limited amount of different fields, but imagine that for each row in the treetableview, there is a hashmap (or something similar) that stores additional information.

Said hashmap would contain the information for all columns in the row. This means that the hashmap would have keys and values for all the keys with the same name as the columns in the javafx treetableview. For example, the hashmap would have the information otherwise stored in the fields `name`, `time` and `price` for example.

Is there a way to achieve this behavior within java and the javafx treetableview? How? Any help is appreciated as it would enable a lot more modular system for me. Thank's in advance.

Comment: Just implement the callback directly to access the hashmap. It's hard to be more specific without seeing some specific code.

Comment: But it is possible, even if the hashmap is inside a subobject of the treetableview data carrier?

Comment: Sure, why not? If you post some sample code I can post an answer but there isn't enough to work with now.

Comment: Okay. What parts do you want? I have a pretty large application. Just the structure, or something more specific?

Comment: The model class for the TreeTableView, or at least the part with the hash map in.

Comment: Thank you. It totally worked to create a custom callback and working down through the data structures.